# Top 5 Values In Time Interval: Tibco Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I want to know how to represent the top 5 values of a set of data in a given month within a bar graph. Example: I have a data set of different names of albums. How do I show the top 5 albums bought within each month?

I already skimmed the data down to top 5, but can't implement the month.

Comment: Could you show a sample dataset and what it is that you wish to display? From what you say, there are three main variables: Album, Month and Sales.

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt an answer, maybe general enough.

In the Properties>Data tab of the bar chart, choose *Limit data using expression* and type:

```
DenseRank(Sum([sales]) over ([album],[month]),'desc',[month])<=5
```

This should limit the display to values of [album] that were ranked between 1 and 5 for the total [sales] over [month].